# Get the sum of a list of integer values

Tags: sql

I'm looking to obtain the sum of a results column. The query is:

```
SELECT  T1.state,
        CAST ((JulianDay(T2.created) - JulianDay(T1.created)) * 24 * 60 * 60 As Integer) AS Interval
FROM    states T1
        INNER JOIN states T2
            ON T1.entity_id = T2.entity_id
            AND T2.created > T1.created
            AND T2.state = "off"
WHERE T1.entity_id = "switch.panel_oficina"
AND T1.state = "on"
AND date(T1.created) = date('now')
GROUP BY T1.entity_id, T1.state, T1.created 
LIMIT 5;
```

This returns

```
state   Interval
on  13421
on  900
on  1380
on  839
on  659
```

So, what I need is the sum of the column "Interval" (in this case 17199)

TIA

Comment: So: `SELECT  T1.state, T1.created, CAST ((JulianDay(T2.created) - JulianDay(T1.created)) * 24 * 60 * 60 As Integer) AS Interval, SUM(CAST ((JulianDay(T2.created) - JulianDay(T1.created)) * 24 * 60 * 60 As Integer)) AS IntervalTotal`

Comment: Gives me this:

https://snipboard.io/sy5EZn.jpg

Comment: Looks like Gordon Linoff posted an answer. He knows is SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the `limit`, use a subquery:

```
SELECT SUM(Interval)
FROM (SELECT T1.state,
              CAST((JulianDay(T2.created) - JulianDay(T1.created)) * 24 * 60 * 60 As Integer) AS Interval
      FROM states T1 JOIN
           states T2
           ON T1.entity_id = T2.entity_id AND
              T2.created > T1.created AND
              T2.state = "off"
      WHERE T1.entity_id = 'switch.panel_oficina' AND
            T1.state = 'on' AND
            date(T1.created) = date('now')
      GROUP BY T1.entity_id, T1.state, T1.created 
      LIMIT 5
     ) t;
```

That said, I think the entire query could be simplified using window functions.  If you want to investigate that, ask a *new* question.  Provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the query is supposed to be doing.